# Accessing the Phone's Music in Windows Phone 7 (and 8)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, audio-player

I'm trying to make a more intuitive music playing app, so my question is: how can I access the music already stored on the phones music library?

I need to get information such as:
-song name
-song artist
-song album
-track number

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MediaLibrary class is a api to access MediaFiles on the phone (Pictures, Music, ...)
you can access the song-collection with the following snippet:

```
using(MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
{
    foreach(var song in library.Songs)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + song.Name);
        Debug.WriteLine("Artist: " + song.Artist.Name);
        Debug.WriteLine("Album: " + song.Album.Name);
    }
}
```

You can also play a song:

```
MediaPlayer.Play(song);
```

Reference the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media in your Project and make sure you dispose the MediaLibrary after your access.

Comment: And also, what does the debug.WriteLine do?

Comment: You could try it out. Include System.Diagnostics;
Never mind. you can assign the song.Name simply to a variable

Comment: But why should I dispose of the MusicLibrary?

Comment: it is good practice to dispose a disposable class. In this very case, the MediaLibrary accesses nativ code. The dispose releases those handlers

Comment: Okay, in addition do you know how to get the album art of a specific song

Comment: The Album Object has a Member called: "Gendre". For more details see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.album_members.aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35030/discussion-between-flo-and-newbie)

Answer (score 0):

```
var library = new MediaLibrary();
```

1. to get all songs.

```
foreach (var item in library.Songs)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Album.ToString());
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Artist.Name);
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Duration);
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.TrackNumber);
}
```

2. get get all albums.

```
foreach (var item in library.Albums)
{ 
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Album ="+ item.Name);
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Artist = "+item.Artist.Name);
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TotalSongs ="+ item.Songs.Count);
}
```

Play song

1. to play a song

   ```
   int index =0;
   MediaPlayer.Play(library.Songs[index]);
   ```
2. to play a collection of song

   ```
   MediaPlayer.Play(library.Songs);
   ```
3. to play a collection of song that start from a specific index. check the song exist in the list

   ```
   int index = 5;
   if(index<=library.Songs.Count-1)  
   MediaPlayer.Play(library.Songs, index);
   ```